# If there is same email address in more than 1 row, hold all messages to be sent, then send them once

Tags: php, mysql, email

Ok, I had given up playing with my code and I had used up all ideas.

I have simple code here that email users about the status of the domain that they sent me. Sometimes, a user sends multiple domain, and I want, instead of sending an email for regarding each domain they sent me, I will just record the status of each domain, then send them once.

here is the code that I am using:

```
function is_url_alive($url) {
    $url = 'http://' . $url;
    $headers = @get_headers($url);
    if ($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {
    echo 'alive';
    } else {
    echo 'down/not alive';
    }
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) :
    $to      = $row['email'];
    $subject = 'The Status of the URL you sent us';
    $message = 'hello! The domain ' . $row['url'] .' that you sent us, using automated system, was found out to be ' . is_url_alive($row['url']);
    mail($to, $subject, $message);
endwhile;
```

======================================================

If you want to know the structure of my database, running this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM domain_db ORDER BY email");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) :
    print_r($row);
    echo '<br />';
endwhile;
```

outputs:

```
Array ( 
    [id] => 1
    [url] => yahoo.com
    [email] => email1@gmail.com
    ) 
Array (
    [id] => 2
    [url] => google.com 
    [email] => email1@gmail.com
    ) 
Array ( 
    [id] => 3 
    [url] => bing.com 
    [email] => email1@gmail.com
    ) 
Array ( 
    [id] => 4
    [url] => ask.com 
    [email] => email1@gmail.com
    ) 
Array ( 
    [id] => 5
    [url] => stackoverflow.com 
    [email] => email1@gmail.com
    ) 
Array ( 
    [id] => 6 
    [url] => digitalpoint.com 
    [email] => email2@gmail.com
    ) 
Array (
    [id] => 7 
    [url] => busilak.com 
    [email] => email2@gmail.com
    )
```

As you can see from the output, the original script will have to send 7 email. But, just sending a mail once to each email, the ideal would only need to send 2 email.

Thanks in advance and more power.

Comment: Haven't I seen this exact same question yesterday?

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes sir, haven't slept for 12hrs because of this. Today ain't that productive, goot stucked.

Answer (score 2):

Store and group the results in an array by using email as key.

Then iterate that array and send mail for each user.

```
$users = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) :
   $users[$row['email']][] = array('url' => $row['url'], 'result' => is_url_alive($row['url']));
endwhile;

foreach($users as $email => $urls) {
   .... send your mail here and implode the urls, results.. 
}
```

Comment: Sir, using SELECT * FROM domain_db GROUP BY email reduces the output to only 2 entries with different email address, other rows disappeared, but, I still have something to do with the other entries.

What does this mean: "Then iterate that array"